# Webpage displaying undefined from prompt() input. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener

Trying to get user input (i.e. hsl(100, 50%, 60%)) value and display the colour and value in a div.

I've only been coding a few months, and i'm new to javascript, so i apologize in advance if this is obvious.

I believe I'm going somewhere wrong with function hslCode.

```js
/* Global variables. */
var newColour;
var newHue;

function hslCode(hue, saturation, lightness) {
  return "hsl(" + hue + ", " + saturation + "%, " + lightness + "%)";
}

function init() {
  /* Event Handlers */
  document.getElementById('choose').onclick = function() {
    prompt();
  }
  document.getElementById('choose').onclick = function() {
    newColour = prompt("Please enter a hsl color. For example: hsl(180 50 50)");
    newHue = hslCode(newColour);
  }
  document.getElementById('choose').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('colourBox').style.backgroundColor = newHue;
    document.getElementById('colourBox').innerHTML = newHue;
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<body>
  <h2 id="theOne">Colour Choice</h2>

  <p><button id="choose">Click to enter the hue</button></p>

  <div id="colourBox"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Every `document.getElementById('choose').onclick` assignment overrides the previous one. Why did you split it up into three event listeners to begin with? You only need one.

Answer (score 1):

There area few problems:

1. You're **overwriting** your click handler by assigning to it three times; only the last one will be used. You probably want to combine those (well, the second two; the first one doesn't do anything useful).
2. Your `hslCode` function expects and uses three parameters, but here:

   ```
   newHue = hslCode(newColour);
   ```

   you're only passing it one argument.

   If you mean for the user to type in all three separated by spaces, you need to handle that, for instance:

   ```
   var parts = newColour.split(" ");
   newHue = hslCode(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
   ```
3. There's no need for `newHue` and `newColour` to be globals.

Updated snippet:

```js
function hslCode(hue, saturation, lightness) {
  return "hsl(" + hue + ", " + saturation + "%, " + lightness + "%)";
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById('choose').onclick = function() {
    var newColour = prompt("Please enter a hsl color. For example: hsl(180 50 50)");
    var parts = newColour.split(" ");
    var newHue = hslCode(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
    document.getElementById('colourBox').style.backgroundColor = newHue;
    document.getElementById('colourBox').innerHTML = newHue;
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<body>
  <h2 id="theOne">Colour Choice</h2>

  <p><button id="choose">Click to enter the hue</button></p>

  <div id="colourBox"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

> ```
>   document.getElementById('choose').onclick = function() {
>     prompt();
>   }
> ```

You assign an event handler to call `prompt` and do nothing with it, but that doesn't matter because then you immediately:

> ```
>   document.getElementById('choose').onclick = function() {
>     newColour = prompt("Please enter a hsl color. For example: hsl(180 50 50)");
>     newHue = hslCode(newColour);
>   }
> ```

**overwrite** that event handler with a new one. It doesn't really matter what that does because you then:

> ```
>   document.getElementById('choose').onclick = function() {
>     document.getElementById('colourBox').style.backgroundColor = newHue;
>     document.getElementById('colourBox').innerHTML = newHue;
>   }
> ```

**overwrite** it again.

You need to write **one** event handler function that both gets the data you want from the user **and** uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You were overwriting the `onclick` events multiple times

```js
/* Global variables. */
var newColour;
var newHue;

function hslCode(hue, saturation, lightness) {
  return "hsl(" + hue + ", " + saturation + "%, " + lightness + "%)";
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById('choose').onclick = function() {
    newColour = prompt("Please enter a hsl color. For example: hsl(180 50 50)");
    newColour = newColour.replace("hsl(","").replace(")", "");
    split = newColour.split(" ");
    newHue = hslCode(split[0],split[1],split[2]);
    document.getElementById("colourBox").style.backgroundColor = newHue;
    document.getElementById('colourBox').innerHTML = newHue;
  };
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<body>
  <h2 id="theOne">Colour Choice</h2>

  <p><button id="choose">Click to enter the hue</button></p>

  <div id="colourBox"> </div>
</body>
```